# Struts 2 Action Type Conversion Of List Using Annotations

Tags: java, struts2

I am trying to create a custom type converter to convert a Collection of objects back and forth from a String.  I have a text area in my form and want to create a new object in the Collection for every line break in the text area on my save.  When displaying the information, I want to loop through the objects in the Collection and turn it into a String with line breaks for my text area.  So far, I am unable to even get my converter to fire or receive any kind of errors based on the annotations that I have.  Below is my class definition:

```
@Conversion()
public class FormsEdit extends JWebCrud{
```

Inside this class I have a List:

```
private List<Formfield> formFields;
```

Inside the Formnfield class I have a Set:

```
private Set<Formfieldopts> formfieldoptses = new HashSet<Formfieldopts>(0);

@TypeConversion(converter = "com.webexchange.actions.tpa.setup.forms.FormFieldOptsConverter")
public void setFormfieldoptses(Set<Formfieldopts> formfieldoptses) {
    this.formfieldoptses = formfieldoptses;
}
```

Can someone please direct me on how to properly setup these annotations to get the Converter to fire?

**Struts 2 Version:** 2.2.1

**Struts Interceptor Stack:**

```
            <interceptor-stack name="stackWithSecurity">
                            <interceptor-ref name="closeHibernateSession" />
            <!--catches exceptions pre or post action class-->
            <interceptor-ref name="exceptionInterceptor" />  
            <interceptor-ref name="security">
                <param name="excludeMethods">executeNoSecurity,executeNoSecurityOrValidation</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias" />
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig" />
            <!-- Puts HTTPResponse and HTTPRequest objects on the action -->
             <interceptor-ref name="openHibernateSession" />
            <!-- Opens a db connection and creates a hibernate session -->
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare" />
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox" /> <!-- Sets unchecked values into the action with a value of 'false' -->
            <interceptor-ref name="params" /><!-- Sets the parameters from the HTTP request to the action -->
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams" />
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError" />
            <!-- adds a field error when the value can't be converted to the right type -->
            <interceptor-ref name="chain">
                <!-- these properties should not be copied from one action to another on a chain -->
                <param name="excludes">dao</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">
                    input,back,cancel,browse,delete,executeNoValidation,executeNoSecurityOrValidation,edit
                </param>
                <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">
                    input,back,cancel,browse,delete,executeNoValidation,executeNoSecurityOrValidation,edit
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
```

**Action Mapping:**

```
        <action name="formsSave"
        class="com.webexchange.actions.tpa.setup.forms.FormsEdit"
        method="save">
        <result name="success">/jsp/centers/tpa/setup/forms/EditForms.jsp
        </result>
        <result name="input">/jsp/centers/tpa/setup/forms/EditForms.jsp
        </result>
    </action>
```

Comment: S2 version? Action/interceptor stack configuration? Anything at DEBUG/devMode log level regarding the scanning or conversion process?

Comment: I have the Struts 2 config in devMode.  I also turned DEBUG on for the root logger.  However, I don't see that Struts outputting anything.

Comment: Nope, I set log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG and have it going out to the ConsoleAppender

Comment: Then you have some other problem; if you're not seeing S2 startup logging with devMode on and at DEBUG level it's going to be difficult to debug.

Comment: Good news!  I found my logging issue.  I have updated the post with the debug info.

Comment: I don't see any debug info, just config (which is helpful). Can you create a minimal, failing example, maybe on github? I don't see anything immediately, obviously wrong, assuming the interceptor stack is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dave for your help.  My s:textarea was not pointing at the Collection I was trying to convert.  After I did that the converter started to fire.  What a total FAIL on my part, sorry.